# How to solder wires to a hobby motor

Tags: dc-motor, soldering, wiring

I am using the cheap 1.5-3v motors from radio shack and I try heating up the connectors on the motor, but I think they are melting inside because in one case the pole now wiggles, and the other case the motor only sorta works depending on how I hold it.

If I don't heat up the metal connectors the solder wont stick, or so ive read.

Comment: You probably should be using some kind of lugs rather than trying to solder to the tabs if that is happening.

Comment: A picture of your motor would help us envision your problem.  So would a link to the motor's datasheet.

Comment: Think carefully about managing your heat. Holding the iron onto a joint for too long (~5sec for that scale) will heat (and potentially damage) many components in the area. Soldering faster will avoid this area heating, but requires you to have really good heat transfer to the piece you wish to solder. Enable this good heat transfer by putting a little dab of solder on the tip of your iron (greatly decreasing the thermal resistance of the iron-part interface).

Comment: Did you tin the wires that you are trying to solder? If you tin both the wire and the terminals, let both cool for 20+ seconds, then try to solder the wire to the terminals you should be able to melt the solder on the two parts together much faster.

Comment: http://comingsoon.radioshack.com/1-5-to-3vdc-hobby-motor/2730223.html#.VWj-9CLn_ok

Comment: soldering wires to that motor is definitely possible, try to follow both tom and jay advices (together) given just above. Practice on the broken motor till you feel good enough for some 'real' soldering.

Answer (score 7):

It's probably better not to tin the lug before you solder to it, instead just brighten it up by scraping it with a razor blade or using some fine sandpaper.

The hemostat will act like a heat sink and suck up the heat that would normally melt the plastic, but only for a little while, so the main thing to remember is to get the soldering at the lug done quickly and use flux cored tin/lead eutectic (Sn63/Pb37) solder if you've got it. If you don't, soldier on with what you've got...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Fantastic answer. Can I ask what temperature for soldering you would use in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can hold the tab with some needle nose pliers which will act as a heat sink to prevent too much heat from traveling into the motor. Solder the outside of the tab. 
Soldering iron--tab--pliers--motor.
Use a high watt soldering iron and solder quickly. The longer you hold the iron to the tab, the more the heat will travel up the metal tab. If you can heat it to solder melting temps faster then you can touch and go and use less heat over-all.
Use a large chisel tip for faster heat transfer and have it loaded with wet solder. The molten solder will help with the heat transfer. I know it seems ironic and is counter-intuitive, but the key is to do it quickly and so you want to transfer the heat all at once then remove it.
Be sure to use flux, tin the wires and the iron and even tin the tab then touch it with the iron just long enough to connect the wire.