# What is this type of small tab-like connector called?

Tags: motor, connector, power-connector

I frequently see this style of connector on small electrics motors.

Is there a standard nomenclature/size specification for this style of connector?

Photo is of a 25mm diameter JGA25-style motor.
[image: Close-up of electrical connection on JGA25 style DC motor.]

Comment: They also serve as a post to solder wire to (gently, avoid melting the plastic.)

Comment: Those are solder eyelets. They can only be used to solder wires to. They are not connectors that mate to other connectors. Even if you found a female terminal that fits, it would slip out over time. Just solder wires to it.

Comment: @DavideAndrea "it would slip out over time". Not necessarily. A lot of male quick-connect terminals have similar holes in them, and female terminals have corresponding dimples or notches that make accidental disconnect practically impossible. Even manual disconnect often requires some tool.

Comment: @Maple. Yes, you are correct about quick-connect disconnects. But OP's motor is _not_ a  quick-connect disconnect. It's a solder eyelet.

Comment: @DavideAndrea That is exactly what the word "similar" means in my comment. Which also was a reply to yours "if you found a female terminal **that fits**". At no time I've suggested that motor tabs were quick-connect. Neither did most of the other comments and answers on this topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *What is this type of small tab-like connector called?*

They are often called solder lugs: -

[image]

Image taken from an answer to this question: [How to solder wires to a hobby motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/173035/how-to-solder-wires-to-a-hobby-motor).

> *Is there a standard nomenclature/size specification for this style of
> connector?*

Not normally a detail that's needed (or provided) when hand soldering cheap DC motors.

You get similar solder lugs on power resistors too: -

[image]

Image from [Farnell](https://at.farnell.com/en-AT/tt-electronics-welwyn/wh100-4r7ji/widerstand-100w-5-4r7/dp/1768203). Plenty of [switches](https://www.mpja.com/Images/31889-large.jpg) use the same technique: -

[image]

Comment: Forgive me, if I may: [this is a solder lug](https://connectorbook.com/classes/terminals_/panel_mount_terminals_/panel_mount_terminals/solder_lugs/i.jpg). I believe that those on the motor are better known and "solder eyelets". If I am wrong, please undo my edits.

Comment: If they are called lugs on potentiometers then they are called lugs on motors @DavideAndrea https://www.switchelectronics.co.uk/passives/potentiometers/control-potentiometers/mono-16mm-solder-lug-potentiometers or here: https://pro.maplin.co.uk/5k-linear-16mm-potentiometer-solder-lugs hence I'm rolling back your edits because eyelet is not a term I naturally use.

Comment: Your comment got me to search the term. You are correct that, when discussing specifically potentiometers, a search for "solder lugs potentiometer" has many more results than "solder terminal potentiometer", or "solder eyelets potentiometer". Thank you for helping me be informed. (BTW, if I replace "potentiometer" with "motor", then "solder terminal" is far more common than "solder lug". If I replace with "switch", lug and terminal have equal numbers of results.)

Comment: There you go!!! All terms are ambiguous LOL @DavideAndrea

Answer (score 11):

They look a bit like small push-on lugs such as [FASTON](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/brands/faston.html?tab=pgp-story) connectors, which are used on some small motors, but they appear to just be solder eyelets. These are bare copper, whereas terminals for push on lugs would tend to be tinned.

You could always solder wires on and put whatever connector you want on the other end of the wires.

Comment: I would put it this way: they _are_ tabs for soldering, but it might be possible to find standard [quick-connect](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/terminals/quick-connects-quick-disconnect-connectors/392) connector (e.g. Faston) with suitable tab width/tab thickness specs.

Comment: @Maple Yeah, hard to tell from the photo what size they are, Going to update my answer.

Comment: Forgive me, but, if I may: 1) Faston is a TE brand, not a type of connector; and 2) even it Faston were a type of connector, the one in the picture isn't one. That is a solder eyelet. It is not designed to be mated with a female terminal.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Updated. You are the connector man after all :D

Comment: Thank you. I see that, but I believe they are solder eyelets, not solder lugs. I believe that [these are solder lugs](https://connectorbook.com/classes/terminals_/panel_mount_terminals_/panel_mount_terminals/solder_lugs/i.jpg).

Comment: @DavideAndrea While I agree that they are most often soldered, the fact that the corners have been clipped is a nod to using a Faston-style connector. The important detail is the blade width: there are at least three in common use.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd in fact, at the Digikey alone there are 1300 active parts of the Faston series, with 10 different tab width choices

Comment: @Maple Plus of course the variants with the clip. I was doing a repair a couple of days ago and spotted a couple of those in time: cunningly covered with black heatshrink :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think they're just for soldering wires (or sometimes used with slots in sensor PCBs).

I looked at about 10 different motor drawings and in only one case were they dimensioned (other than length, which was 3.5 or 4.0mm) and in that case only the width (2mm) was specified.

I would expect thickness to be specified if they were intended for a spade connector. That said, it's possible that something like [this](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=63391&DocType=Customer+Drawing&DocLang=English) would fit, however note the tight tolerance on the thickness (+/-one thou) and also, IME, they are usually thin and often not plated so the connection may not be reliable.

Answer (score 1):

They look, to me, like [quick-connect connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_connector)

Its easy to find both male and female connectors online, e.g. Amazon.